# Eclipse OnClickListener MainActivity errors

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I got a problem with my program.

Here's the error:

```
The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)
```

Here's the code:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnInitListener, OnClickListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    }

    public void OnClick (View view){
        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
        tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

    public void onInit (int status){
        Button button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
        tts.setLanguage(Locale.GERMAN);
        tts.setSpeechRate(1);
    }
}
```

I just started programming with `eclipse` and I'm really a beginner.

So what do I have to do to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
The type MainActivity must implement the inherited abstract method View.OnClickListener.onClick(View)
```

You need to implement `onClick(View)`. Since it was not implemented you get the error.

So Change to

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view){ //OnClick  You has O in caps
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Add Override annotation and change `OnClick` to `onClick`.

Answer (score 1):

Please clean your project and build it again

You have to implement all the methods provided by OnClickListener interface.
when you implement onClickListener in your activity your onclick method should be overided like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[`OnClickListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) is an interface. You have to implement all the methods provided by this interface.

I think this is what you wanna do here :

```
public void OnClick (View view){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

But this is not the right signature, it should be :

```
@Override
public void onClick (View view){ //note the 'o'
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```

Note that [adding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) the `@Override` annotation is not required but it helps to prevent errors. If a method marked with `@Override` fails to correctly override a method in one of its superclasses, the compiler generates an error.

Answer (score 1):

You almost had it!  Just change the name of the method to `onClick` so that it implements the`onclick` method as specified by the [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) interface.

When a class implements an interface it must provide an implementation for each method listed on the interface.  The classes implementation must match the signature (name, arguments, return type) specified on the interface.

```
public void onClick (View view){
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.editText1);
    tts.speak(et.getText().toString(), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}
```